# Properties file with Spring - how to use them

Tags: spring

I have a properties file `sample.properties` put in project's root `resource` folder with this content:

`auditorium.name=New York`.

Now in `spring.xml` I try to access some of them with following syntax:

```
<bean id="auditorium1" class="hometask.domain.Auditorium">
    <property name="name" value="${auditorium.name}" />
</bean>
```

But in run-time this property is not resolved. name is set to string `${auditorium.name}` instead of `New York`.

Is there anything else I should set up to have it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should set-up the placeholder of your properties this way:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:sample.properties"/>
```

Comment: FileNotFoundException: classpath:auditorium.properties - any help with that please?

Comment: the file is `sample.properties` , isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, file name is ok. But maybe it's not moved to classpath ? How can I check it?

Comment: Check under WEB-INF/classes/ it should be there .

Comment: It is not web project. I have only target, and under target i have: classes/generated-sources, generated-test-sources, resources, test-classes folders

Comment: you need to build it , or refresh the project.

Comment: I did it... It is simple app made from scratch with only core spring rependencies in pom.xml

Comment: you need to find the path of your file  in your project assembly / classpath and refer it on the location attribute